# How to program "key down"s speed programmatically?(Python)

Tags: python, sendkeys

In python, I'm using SendKey module to perform "key down"
My curiosity starts with pressing speed.
When using SendKey, it presses with machine speed. I want to program it to slow down like human speed. Is it possible in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using ctypes.
It can be implemented in win32 apis